# Converting MD5Bytes and getBytes Java code to PHP

Tags: java, php

I have been given this sample java code that I need to convert into PHP

JAVA

```
String rawStr = logistics_interface + signKey;
String data_digest = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(MD5Bytes(rawStr.getBytes("utf-8"))), "utf-8");
```

I have been using this PHP:

```
$rawStr = $logistics_interface . $signKey;
$data_digest = base64_encode(md5(utf8_encode($rawStr)));
```

Using these test values:

```
$logistics_interface = '<order>helloworld</order>';
$signKey = '123';
```

My PHP code gives:

```
ZWUwNGZmMWU2MTQ1NGRmOTcwN2U2ZmY3MmNlMjlkOTk=
```

But I am being told by the API supplier that the correct value of $data_digest should be:

```
7gT/HmFFTflwfm/3LOKdmQ==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `MD5Bytes` returns the plain bytes of the MD5 result, in PHP the `md5` function returns a human-readable hex-representation of the bytes, hence to get the exact same result you get in Java you need to *undo* the binary-to-hex conversion first with `hex2bin`

```
$data_digest = base64_encode(hex2bin(md5($rawStr)));
```

should give you the exact same result: [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ccbbaee643428a0d405f2ab015d2d5e4f7bfa4ee)

Comment: @tkausl I have a question, could you help me answer?
 In Java I see:
`System.out.println("hello world".getBytes("UTF-8"))`
has result
`[B@a67c67e`
How can I have this result in PHP? Thanks

Comment: @Khaihkd I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `[B@a67c67e` is generated by the default `toString` method, it is __not__ the content of the byte array. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("hello world".getBytes("UTF-8")))` to print the array.

Comment: @tkausl I mean in PHP has any function like `getBytes` in Java

Comment: @Khaihkd In PHP a string is just an array of bytes, so just use the string as-is. You might need to convert it to UTF-8 though, if it isn't already a UTF-8 string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: @tkausl in Java encrypt string `hello world` I receive `[B@a67c67e`, in PHP can I encrypt as Java?

Comment: @Khaihkd you get `[B@a67c67e` because this is the identifier for this specific byte array. Again, this is __not__ the encrypted data.